# Row deleted only by click twice

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a validation Rule in the remove row method with error message, but this message appear only when clicked delete row twice instead of one.
I don't know what's the cause of this issue, any help please.

```
 public void remove() {

    RowIterator rs = getStStore();

    if (rs.getRowCount() > 0) {

        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("model.AsconBundle", ADFContext.getCurrent().getLocale());

        throw new JboException(bundle.getString("DELETE_MASTER_DETAIL_VALIDTION"));

    } else {

        super.remove();

    }

}
```

Comment: did you try the immediate=true attribute. Share the code if you want more help/.

Comment: the first thing i tried is that make immediate= true but it didn't work, i will edit my post to share code.

Comment: a public void ? Is it an Action attribute ? Did you try with and ActionListener Event ? If you can share the jsf as well :)

Comment: i am calling the remove method from the entity impl, and the actionListener of the button is : actionListener="#{bindings.Delete.execute}"

Comment: i am wondering why it can't show me the error message from the first delete click and show it in the second.

Comment: Yeah it's usually because there is a form javascript validation in the way before going all the way to the server VOImpl. That's why you have to experiment with the immediate = true and check if it's in a form or something else that have another validation